# asp.net convert table to excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, postback, export-to-excel

I have a table which is created dynamically in the Page_Load, basically on every PostBack.

I am using this sample code to try and convert it to excel:

```
<table id="table1" runat="server"> 
            <tr> 
                <td>tes1</td> 
                <td>tes2</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>tete1</td> 
                <td>tete2</td> 
            </tr> 
 </table>
```

code behind:

```
 private DataSet GetTableCellsToDataSet()
        {
          HtmlTable tb =  table1;   //table1 is the id of HTML Table
          int rowscount = table1.Rows.Count;
          int columncount = 2;

           DataTable dt=new DataTable();
          dt.Columns.Add("a1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
          dt.Columns.Add("a2", Type.GetType("System.String"));


          for (int i = 0; i < rowscount; i++)
          {
              HtmlTableCellCollection tcs = tb.Rows[i].Cells;

              DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
              dr["a1"] = tcs[0].InnerText;
              dr["a2"] = tcs[1].InnerText;
              dt.Rows.Add(dr);
          }
          DataSet ds = new DataSet();
          ds.Tables.Add(dt);

return ds;
    }
```

and

```
private void convertToExcel(DataSet dsBook) 
    { 
        try 
        { 

            int rows = dsBook.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1; 
            int cols = dsBook.Tables[0].Columns.Count; 


            string ExcelFileName = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "abcd.xls"); 
            if (File.Exists(ExcelFileName)) 
            { 
                File.Delete(ExcelFileName); 
            } 
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ExcelFileName, false); 
            writer.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("<?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("<Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\""); 
            writer.WriteLine(" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\""); 
            writer.WriteLine(" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\""); 
            writer.WriteLine(" xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\""); 
            writer.WriteLine(" xmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" <DocumentProperties xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <Author>Automated Report Generator Example</Author>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("  <Created>{0}T{1}Z</Created>", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd"), DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM:SS"))); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <Company>51aspx.com</Company>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <Version>11.6408</Version>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" </DocumentProperties>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" <ExcelWorkbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <WindowHeight>8955</WindowHeight>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <WindowWidth>11355</WindowWidth>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <WindowTopX>480</WindowTopX>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <WindowTopY>15</WindowTopY>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" </ExcelWorkbook>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" <Styles>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <Style ss:ID=\"Default\" ss:Name=\"Normal\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <Alignment ss:Vertical=\"Bottom\"/>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <Borders/>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <Font/>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <Interior/>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <Protection/>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  </Style>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <Style ss:ID=\"s21\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <Alignment ss:Vertical=\"Bottom\" ss:WrapText=\"1\"/>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  </Style>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" </Styles>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" <Worksheet ss:Name=\"MyReport\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount=\"{0}\" ss:ExpandedRowCount=\"{1}\" x:FullColumns=\"1\"", cols.ToString(), rows.ToString())); 
            writer.WriteLine("   x:FullRows=\"1\">"); 

            //generate title 
            writer.WriteLine("<Row>"); 
            foreach (DataColumn eachCloumn in dsBook.Tables[0].Columns) 
            { 
                writer.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s21\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">"); 
                writer.Write(eachCloumn.ColumnName.ToString()); 
                writer.WriteLine("</Data></Cell>"); 
            } 
            writer.WriteLine("</Row>"); 

            //generate data 
            foreach (DataRow eachRow in dsBook.Tables[0].Rows) 
            { 
                writer.WriteLine("<Row>"); 
                for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow != cols; currentRow++) 
                { 
                    writer.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s21\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">"); 
                    writer.Write(eachRow[currentRow].ToString()); 
                    writer.WriteLine("</Data></Cell>"); 
                } 
                writer.WriteLine("</Row>"); 
            } 
            writer.WriteLine("  </Table>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <WorksheetOptions xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <Selected/>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <Panes>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("    <Pane>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("     <Number>3</Number>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("     <ActiveRow>1</ActiveRow>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("    </Pane>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   </Panes>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  </WorksheetOptions>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" </Worksheet>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" <Worksheet ss:Name=\"Sheet2\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <WorksheetOptions xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  </WorksheetOptions>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" </Worksheet>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" <Worksheet ss:Name=\"Sheet3\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  <WorksheetOptions xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("  </WorksheetOptions>"); 
            writer.WriteLine(" </Worksheet>"); 
            writer.WriteLine("</Workbook>"); 
            writer.Close(); 
            Response.Write("<script language=\"javascript\">" + "alert('" + "convert completed!')" + "</script>"); 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            Response.Write("<script language=\"javascript\">" + "alert('" + "error! " + ex.Message + "')" + "</script>"); 
        } 

    }
```

The above does work when I make pre-defined table in the aspx page but not for my dynamic table.

```
convertToExcel(GetTableCellsToDataSet()); creates the file so if I call that onClick of an asp:button it actually only displays the headers of the table (because the table gets recreated on postback).
```

How to fix the above?

Comment: I don't line the stream writer approach. I would prefer http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample.

Comment: How to cache the object?